# Passing user data from Connect With Facebook button into Modx profile fields

Tags: facebook, modx-revolution

I've been trying to use the Connect With Facebook button on a Modx Revolution site.  I've been following along with this guide here: http://edwardawebb.com/web-development/facebook-login-modx-sites.

So far, I have the button creating the new user, but it's not passing through the data from the Facebook profile to the Modx profile fields.  In addition to that, I need a way to tell the user what their username is so they can login with that username if they chose to (as opposed to using the Connect with Facebook button again).

Here is what my snippet looks like that is creating the profile from the Connect with Facebook button: http://pastebin.com/jdf5zrA8

Eventually, I want to collect more user data than what's in there now, but I figured I would start simple for now.  Since this is a bit more advanced than my skills are.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just about to release an extra for MODX Revolution which will do what you need - see http://www.hyper-typer.com/news/facebook-login-modx and http://www.github.com/freelancewebdev/fblogin - particularly the snippets in core/components/snippets.